# How to loop through all rows in DataTables jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using jquery plugin **D**ataTables for building  nice table

```
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "data": source
});
```

I would like that make an each for all rows in table

Unfortunately this way may be out of date and does't work with new version  (it launchs an error)

```
$(table.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {

});
```

And this way only works only  for visibles rows (10 first rows because other rows are paginated)

```
 table.each( function ( value, index ) {
    console.log( 'Data in index: '+index+' is: '+value );
} );
```

Do you known how to loop to all rows  please?

Comment: what do you mean? do you wish to display all rows? if so, then you can try this: `var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "paging":false
});`

Comment: Thanks for answere,no, I don't want to display all rows, I want to dynamically loop all rows in code,  even rows which are paginated

Comment: maybe you can just used the data.. I mean your source of data that you fill in the dataTable..  I'm not sure..

Comment: yes, good idea, but it happens that init dataTable data has been changed by user ( I have a system for allowing user to edit , add, and delete rows without redraw all dataTable). And i wana know things like for exemple what row is the 27th displayed

Comment: `Unfortunately this way may be out of date and does't work with new version (it launchs an error)` What is the error that it throws?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I finally found:

```
 var data = table.rows().data();
 data.each(function (value, index) {
     console.log(`For index ${index}, data value is ${value}`);
 });
```

Comment: Warning: This only iterates over the data itself that was passed in to dataTables - so any HTML you give it will be a string in this method.

Comment: I finally found you. Thanks a lot for the answer

Comment: How to get specific column values only?

Comment: I only get the first page data. How to get the next page ?

Comment: You can do it even easier: 
`var data = table.data();`

Answer (score 12):

Datatables have an iterator for each row [rows().every()](http://datatables.net/reference/api/rows%28%29.every%28%29) with `this` referring to the context of the current row being iterated.

```
tableName.rows().every(function(){
    console.log(this.data());
});
```

Comment: By this we will get rows of current pager. How can i get all pagers data.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using the legacy DataTables then you can get all the rows **even the paginated ones**, as shown below...

```
table.fnGetNodes(); // table is the datatables object.
```

So we can loop through the rows by using `.each()` method provided by `jQuery`.

```
jQuery(table.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
// You can use `jQuery(this).` to access each row, and process it further.            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

for example, this data has three fields UserID, UserName and isActive and we want to show only active users
The following code will return all the rows.

```
var data = $('#myDataTable').DataTable().rows().data();
```

We will print only active users

```
data.each(function (value, index) {
  if (value.isActive)
  {
     console.log(value.UserID);
     console.log(value.UserName);
  }
});
```